# Activity with no fragment shows white background before finish

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity, fragment-backstack

I have added number of fragments using fragmentTransaction's add and replace methods. After an action, I removed all the fragments in layout and when the back stack is empty, I called finish() on the activity. However before the finish is executed, the activity background (white) shows for few milliseconds. How do I make sure the activity finish as soon as the last fragment is removed so the background of the activity doesn't show?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the fragment in the first place? Just finish() the activity and its fragments are also gone.

Comment: I am building a stack for notification. So when the notification is tapped, I am opening say fragment B but before that I add fragment A to backstack so when the user is on B, back press takes them back to A and another back press should finish the activity since stack is now empty. This where the activity background shows before its finishes.

Comment: AS @laalto stated, when your backstack fragment count is 1 just finish activity instead of popping up fragment and finish activity afterwards.